# Is it possible to concat string array with Promise<string[]> to return Promise<String[]> in typescript/javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

```
public async getPromiseArray(from: number, to: number): Promise<String[]> {
    const someArray = this.someArray;
    const arr1 = someArray.slice(from, from + 2); // This returns an array of string
    const arr2 = this.storageService.get(from + 3, to) // This returns Promise<String[]>

    // Is is possible to return a promise<String[]> which is a concat of arr1 and arr2
}
```

I could await for arr2 and return the array of string but is it possible to directly return Promise<String[]> from this method?

Comment: There's nothing in this that is actually async. You can return a promise that wraps your string but the processing of that string will have already happened and the promise will already have resolved.

Comment: `return [...arr1, ...(await arr2)]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
public async getPromiseArray(from: number, to: number): Promise<String[]> {
    try {
        const someArray = this.someArray;
        const arr1 = someArray.slice(from, from + 2);
        const arr2 = await this.storageService.get(from + 3, to);
       resolve(arr1.concat(arr2))
    }
    reject(arr1.concat(arr2))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is!

Just `.then` your promise, and concat there:

```
//If you return a promise and don't use `await`, then there's no need for `async`
public getPromiseArray(from: number, to: number): Promise<String[]> {
    const someArray = this.someArray;
    const arr1 = someArray.slice(from, from + 2); // This returns an array of string
    const arr2 = this.storageService.get(from + 3, to) // This returns Promise<String[]>

    // Is is possible to return a promise<String[]> which is a concat of arr1 and arr2
    return arr2.then(arr2 => arr1.concat(arr2))
}
```